# Print data before fetch

Tags: php, mysql

Following is my code.

```
<?php
            if(isset($_POST['Generate']))
            {
                $emp = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['employee']);
                $startD = $_POST['from'];
                $endD = $_POST['to'];
                $search = "SELECT leaveregister.*, users.first_name, users.last_name FROM leaveregister INNER JOIN users ON leaveregister.employee=users.id WHERE employee = '$emp' AND startDate >= '$startD' AND endDate <= '$endD'";
                $dosearch = mysql_query($search);
                if(mysql_num_rows($dosearch) > 0)
                {
                    echo '<span>Employee : <strong>'.$row['first_name'].'</strong></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>From : <strong>'.$startD.'</strong></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>To : <strong>'.$endD.'</strong></span><br><br><br>' ;
                    echo '<table border="1" class="table table-bordered">';
                    echo '<thead><th>Emp</th><th>Leave Type</th><th>Leave Duration</th><th>Start</th><th>End</th><th>Remarks</th></thead>';
                    echo '<tbody>';
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($dosearch))
                    {
                        echo '<tr><td>'.$row['employee'].'</td><td>'.$row['leaveType'].'</td><td>'.$row['leaveDays'].'</td><td>'.$row['startDate'].'</td><td>'.$row['endDate'].'</td><td>'.$row['remarks'].'</td></tr>';
                        }
                    echo '</tbody></table>';
                    }
                    else
                    {                       
                    echo "Not Found!!";
                    }
                }
        ?>
```

The query generates some leave details of a given employee.
I used INNER JOIN to take the `first_name` & `last_name` from `users` table.
The problem is, I want to print Employee's First Name before the query fetch inside the table.
Actually, I want to print it on after the second if.

```
echo '<span>Employee : <strong>'.$row['first_name'].'</strong></span>
```

I know I can't use `$row` there. 
Then how can I print it?

Comment: The `mysql_` constructor is [**deprecated as of PHP 5.5**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), and is outright [**removed in PHP 7**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7#extmysql). Please consider switching to either [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), ensuring that you also use [**parameterised queries**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent SQL Injection :)

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for either [**nested queries**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-sub-queries.htm) or two separate queries to the table. Though I can't really recommend how to do that with MySQL, as it would expose you to serious security vulnerabilities, and thus it would be unethical to do so. Instead, I suggest re-writing your code in MySQLi or PDO. It only takes a second, and will really help you in the long run :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like this code... You need to use Two while loop so you can use `mysql_data_seek()` function it reset the first loop and runs the second loop normal...My recommendation about MySql is not good to try to use MySqli.

```
if(isset($_POST['Generate']))
    {
        $emp = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['employee']);
        $startD = $_POST['from'];
        $endD = $_POST['to'];
        $search = "SELECT leaveregister.*, users.first_name, users.last_name FROM leaveregister INNER JOIN users ON leaveregister.employee=users.id WHERE employee = '$emp' AND startDate >= '$startD' AND endDate <= '$endD'";
        $dosearch = mysql_query($search);
        if(mysql_num_rows($dosearch) > 0)
        {
            while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($dosearch)){
             $name = $rows['first_name'];
            }
            echo '<span>Employee : <strong>'.$name.'</strong></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>From : <strong>'.$startD.'</strong></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>To : <strong>'.$endD.'</strong></span><br><br><br>' ;
            echo '<table border="1" class="table table-bordered">';
            echo '<thead><th>Emp</th><th>Leave Type</th><th>Leave Duration</th><th>Start</th><th>End</th><th>Remarks</th></thead>';
            echo '<tbody>';
            mysql_data_seek($dosearch, 0);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($dosearch))
            {
                echo '<tr><td>'.$row['employee'].'</td><td>'.$row['leaveType'].'</td><td>'.$row['leaveDays'].'</td><td>'.$row['startDate'].'</td><td>'.$row['endDate'].'</td><td>'.$row['remarks'].'</td></tr>';
                }
            echo '</tbody></table>';
            }
            else
            {                       
            echo "Not Found!!";
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have tried.
`$name` prints successfully.
But the Second `while ` is not working & prints nothing.

Comment: Can you please explain how to use `mysql_data_seek` ?

Comment: I added that code also did you try that `mysql_data_seek($dosearch, 0);` before this line `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($dosearch))`. And double check the variable name `$row` is not same for two while loop

Comment: Thank you Nawin. Solved.